# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection when running oracle DB as docker container and trying to connect via Tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, docker, tomcat

I have setup a docker container with oracle db using following yml.

```
version: '3'
services:
  oracle:
    image: "carloscastillo/rgt-oracle-xe-11g"
    ports:
      - "49160:22"
      - "49161:1521"
      - "49162:8080"
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/u01/app/oracle carloscastillo/rgt-oracle-xe-11g"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
      - ORACLE_ENABLE_XDB=true
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

I'm trying to access  the db in tomcat.This is the Context.xml db configurations.

```
<Resource name="ORACLE" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
username="system" password="oracle" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:49161/xe"/>
```

Added the relevant driver into class path too.Still getting the error
"IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection ".
Also tried url as jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:49161:xe.This is the first time i'm doing this.Could not solve what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Sandali95! How about your tomcat process. Is it running in a container as well? bridge mode?

Comment: Hi @BjarteBrand , No it's not.Running tomcat in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your docker-compose. Worked out of the box on my MacOS. I suggest you add double-forslash to your connect string.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:49161/xe
```

The double-forslash is to tell your JDBC driver, "Hey, do not try to use any environment information except what I give you solely on this one line" - EZConnect (EasyConnect)"

An advice is always to make sure you can connect from sqlplus or sqlcl before moving on the any app-lib (java,python,php,etc..). Like so:

```
sqlplus system/oracle@//localhost:49161/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Nov 11 13:11:30 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

system@XE> @inst

INSTANCE INFORMATION

Ins                                                                          Stat Para             DB     Shdn
  # Instance             Host                   Version    Up since          us   llel Th# Arch    Status Pend Logins  SGA Size (GB)
--- -------------------- ---------------------- ---------- ----------------- ---- ---- --- ------- ------ ---- ------- -------------
  1 XE                   5600801e8a25           11.2.0.2.0 11.11.20 11:58:33 OPEN NO     1 STOPPED ACTIVE NO   ALLOWED             1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

I have seen plenty of times where the database listener isn't started although the container and database processes are running. My approach to this is

```
# restart the container until it works. Second or third time it normally works....
docker-container restart oracle 

# fire up the listener. Remember to run as 'oracle' and wait for 10s until the service_name 'XE' is exposed in the listener process
docker-compose exec -u oracle oracle sh -c "lsnrctl stop;lsnrctl start;echo 'alter database register' | sqlplus / as sysdba; sleep 10; lsnrctl status"

# For real world CI/CD scenarios I will add a healthcheck to the docker-compose service.
    healthcheck:
      test: sql -L -S sys/oracle@localhost:1521/XE as sysdba < /dev/null |grep 'ORA-'; if [[ $$? == 1 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 20
      start_period: 40s
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @BjarteBrand,Thanks for the quick reply.
 i tried loggin to sl*plus.

`sqlplus system/oracle@//localhost:49161/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Nov 11 15:35:09 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener


Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> @inst
SP2-0310: unable to open file "inst.sql"`

Comment: Even with this i can access the databse through sql*plus.But when trying to connect with eclipse, it still gives the same error.

Comment: @Sandali95 ORA-12541: TNS:no listener, I have seen this plenty of times working with oracle docker containers. Listener process isn't started. My attack is to just restart the container. Eventually, both oracle instance and listener will start. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Worked fine after restarting :D